# MySQL Subquery result array

Tags: mysql

I want to use an array of (id_1)ids from a selection on table_1 to get all rows from table_2 where id_2 = id_1

```
  SELECT field_b
  FROM table_2
  WHERE id_2 IN (
         SELECT id_1 FROM table_1 WHERE field_a = 1234
  );
```

Below are example of my tables for reference:

```
  mysql> select * from table_1;
    +-------+---------+
    |  id_1 | field_a |
    +-------+---------+
    |     1 |    1234 |
    +-------+---------+
    |     2 |    1234 |
    +-------+---------+


mysql> select * from table_2;
+---------+---------+
|    id_2 | field_b |
+---------+---------+
|     1   |  5678   |
+-------+-----------+
|     2   |  0013   |
+-------+-----------+
```

Comment: do you want to make simple INNER JOIN ? SELECT * from table_2 INNER JOIN table_1 on table_1.id_1 = table_2.id_2 ? You can add whatever conditions you want, for example WHERE field_a = 1234

Comment: The code you posted using `IN` should work...

Comment: @Martin that's a good point, now that you mention it.  I wonder what trouble the OP is actually having?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would an INNER JOIN work just as well well for you?

```
SELECT field_b
FROM table_2
INNER JOIN table_1
    ON table_2.id_2 = table_1.id_1
WHERE table_2.field_a=1234
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is what you need:

```
SELECT * FROM table_2 t2
INNER JOIN table_1 t1
ON t2.id_2 = t1.id_1
WHERE t1.field_a = 1234
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
SELECT field_b
FROM table_2
WHERE EXISTS 
      ( SELECT * 
        FROM table_1 
        WHERE field_a = 1234
          AND table_2.id_2 = table_1.id_1
      )
```